# Can I change state key names from reducer?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I apologise if this is a stupid question, but I'm not sure how to get the functionality I'd like and the docs seem to not include it.

My current rootReducer has the following state structure

```
export interface GameStatusState {
  gameLevel: number,
  playerHealth: number,
  playerCoins: number,
  playerMoves: number
}
```

However, I'd like it to be like so;

```
gameStatus: {
   gameLevel: number,
   playerHealth: number,
   playerCoins: number,
   playerMoves: number
}
```

I can achieve this using:

```
combineReducers({gameStatus: rootReducer})
```

But is there a more conventional way I can do this?

Comment: If you want your reducer to have another deepth level you could just define more complex structure (adding gameStatus as parent field in state.

Comment: @MaciejTrojniarz Sure, but then for each reducer action I'd need to reference state.gameStatus rather than simply state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly how you're supposed to do it.

In Redux, we normally divide up our reducer logic based on "slices" of state. The root state structure is defined by whatever the root reducer function returns, and that root reducer is normally generated using `combineReducers()`.

So, calling `combineReducers({someFieldName: someReducerFunction})` says we want our root state object to have a `state.someFieldName` field, and the updates to that section of the state are handled by `someReducerFunction`.

For more details, see the Redux [Initializing State](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state) and [Using `combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers) docs pages, as well as the new ["Redux Essentials" core docs tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).